# Parsley validation is not running (even on a plain html file)

Tags: javascript, validation, twitter-bootstrap, parsley.js

I love [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html)'s style of form validation with beautfiul background-color at the form elements (green -> correct, red -> wrong), but I can't figure out how to implement this.

I followed the instructions line per line, but it's not working. Maybe my other js resources disturb the flow, so I made a plain new html site, but it also doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

My plain .html looks like that:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.2/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pars/parsley.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="demo-form" data-validate="parsley">
  <label for="fullname">Full Name * :</label>
  <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" data-required="true" />
  <input type="submit" value="ok" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm leaving the field blank, click "ok", and nothing happens.

I was able (don't ask me how) to run Parsley for a short time, but without the fancy background-colors. Do you know what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsley does not manage colors / UI. It justs add / remore css classes depending on validation.

By default: `parsley-error` and `parsley-success`. They could be changed in parsley config.

But you will have still to do some css to tell that `parsley-success` for example has green background and `parsley-error` a red one.

Comment: ok great, thanks. now it works. i also think that my parsley.js was broken because i had to re-download it!